# database schema for recurring orders that change

Tags: mysql, database, schema, recurring, orders

I am creating a subscription site where the actual products being ordered can change on a month-to-month basis. I'm looking for an efficient way to handle the products associated with the current order and retain the products that were delivered with previous months.

Brief schema below:

orders

```
id
customer_id
subscription_id
shipping_...
billing_...
```

order_products

```
id
order_id
product_id
quantity
price
total
```

order_invoices

```
id
order_id
date_shipped
```

order_invoice_products

```
id
order_invoice_id
product_id
```

subscriptions

```
id
```

Thanks for the help..

Comment: http://WhatHaveYouTried.com/ ? It's not really a good idea to ask SO to design your application and your schema for you.

Comment: It's just a question about best practice, if you don't want to help then don't :) There are plenty of similar questions on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You have to record the dates (months) of the orders.
Add a field for this to the order table.

Comment: I do have that as in (created, modified) however that will mean I would need multiple order rows when the original order is a recurring one. Perhaps 2 more tables such as 'order_invoices' and 'order_invoice_products'?